# Update child counter based on parent in Oracle SQL using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have two tables `Invoice` and `InvoiceLine`. `Invoice` is the parent and `InvoiceLine` is the child.

Table `InvoiceLine` has a column `lineNr` which should store values based on the parent table. So for example invoice1 should have lineNr 1, 2, 3, etc... Invoice2 should also have lineNr 1, 2, 3, etc...

Now the `lineNr` is wrong because the counter was made regardless the parent table `Invoice`, so for example invoice2 has lineNr 4, 5, 6...etc.

How can I fix the line counter in the `InvoiceLine` table using PL/SQL?

Can someone help me please? I think a loop is needed.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 0):

The way you described it, "parent-child" relationship is *fake*. You should make it true within the database, not on a paper (or in your thoughts).

Because, if those were really parent-child tables, there would be a referential integrity constraint which wouldn't let you enter invalid values (i.e. child table couldn't possibly have `linenr` values that don't exist in parent table).

Should've been something like this:

```
SQL> create table invoice
  2    (linenr      number constraint pk_inv primary key,
  3     whatever    varchar2(10)
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> create table invoiceline
  2    (id_invline  number constraint pk_invline primary key,
  3     linenr      number constraint fk_invline_inv references invoice(linenr),
  4     whatever    varchar2(2)
  5    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

I presumed that `linenr` column makes foreign key constraint.

---

Or, possibly a composite primary (and then foreign) key:

```
SQL> create table invoice
  2    (id_inv      number,
  3     linenr      number,
  4     whatever    varchar2(10),
  5     --
  6     constraint pk_inv primary key (id_inv, linenr)
  7    );

Table created.

SQL> create table invoiceline
  2    (id_invline  number constraint pk_invline primary key,
  3     id_inv      number,
  4     linenr      number,
  5     whatever    varchar2(2),
  6     --
  7     constraint fk_invline_inv foreign key (id_inv, linenr)
  8       references invoice (id_inv, linenr)
  9    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

---

What to do now? Who knows? How will you know which rows to change to which values? Perhaps using `update` statement as one that follows:

```
update invoiceline b set
  b.linenr = (select a.linenr
              from invoice a
              where a.id_inv = b.id_inv
             )
where exists (select null
              from invoice c
              where c.id_inv = b.id_inv
             );
```

If you wonder "Why `exists`?", the answer is: because of that *fake* parent-child relationship. There's no guarantee that every child row has its parents, so to avoid setting `linenr` to `NULL` for rows without parents.